# What is meant by "Windows doesn't support proper dynamic linking?"

Tags: c++, linux, windows, dll

I've read the documentation for Linux calls `dlopen()` and `dlsym()` that opens a dynamic library and loads a symbol in the library, respectively.

These calls seem to be equivalent to Windows' `LoadLibrary()` and `GetProcAddress()`.

I read "Windows doesn't support proper dynamic linking" in this post: [Running LLVM passes on Windows 10 gives no output in terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41943353/running-llvm-passes-on-windows-10-gives-no-output-in-terminal/41980033#41980033).

What is the reason Linux and Windows dynamic library calls differ?

Is the only difference that dynamic libraries on Linux can load symbols in executables? But this would imply that executables are also libraries on Linux, since `dlopen()` operates on dynamic libraries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows *does* support proper dynamic linking. The difference is that Windows does not support *improper* dynamic linking, where you link an executable against a library (i.e. the wrong way around). This mistake is impossible on Windows because its executables do not have an export table.

That said, your logic is a bit flawed. Executables and dynamic libraries don't differ that much, even on Windows. `LoadLibrary` will in fact load executables; it's `GetProcAdddress` which fails.

As for the plugin logic, that's pretty easy to arrange in C++ using abstract (pure virtual) classes as interfaces.

Comment: Do you know why Windows chooses not to have export tables for its executables?

Comment: Would you link it show how the plugin is made in C++?

Comment: I guess you mean "where you link a library against an executable".

Comment: @Shuzheng: That's the right way. I was explicitly talking about the wrong way, where you try to link an executable against a library. As to why Windows "chose"  not to have it, that's suggesting that the default is to have such a table. But such a table only exists if a linker creates it, and _that_ is a conscious decision.. So the proper question is why the Linux and UNIX linkers chose to create export tables.

Comment: I'm confused. When you say "link X against Y",  does that means that Y loads X and resolve symbols from it?

Comment: No, it means that X uses functions exported from Y. That's almost the same, but on Linux you can have the odd situation that a library uses functions exported by the executable instead of the other way around. The executable still loads the library, though.

Comment: But you write "link executable against library" is improper dynamic linking. But this is the normal way dynamic linking takes place on Windows.

Comment: @Shuzheng: Hmm, fair point - now you got me confused. Still, the fundamental point remains. An EXE never has no export table, but only an import table, while on Linux an ELF executable can have an export table like a library. However, that's just an artifact of the ELF format, and not good design.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance.

Comment: But you *can* use functions exported from the executable in a library dll.
The functions have to be dllexport'ed, and then just create an export library und use it when linking the library dll.
And the executable has to be the one using the dll.